# React-Apollo-GraphQL Generic Queries and Mutations

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, apollo

This question is more about **design**.
In my heavy app and want to implement **generic** ***mutation*** and ***query*** action.
My first thought was to implement a function that encapsulates all queries or mutations in one place. Like this:

```
function query(props) {
  const Query = require('dynamic/query/based/on/props.path.gql');
  const { data, loading, ...} = useQuery(Query, ...);
  return { data, loading, ... };
}
```

then use it

```
import Query form './query';
function SomeMainFunction(props) {
  cont { data, loading, ...} = Query(props);
  return data.map(...);
}
```

(Similar for mutation)
It seems to me like this is causing unnecessary rerendering even with `React.memo`.
The second approach was to make use of `useContext`. But I don't really see how to deal with network status in this case. Meaning having `loading` `true` and then `false`. Or will `useQuery` handle this by re-rendering the component once the data arrives?

Of cause, the third solution is to implement this logic directly in the function/component. Something I don't want because of code splitting.

Answer (score 0):

I end up using the above-mentioned design with proper use of `memo` and it solved my issue.